# What's a word to describe something that is "non-English?"

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice, word-usage, expressions

I was trying to write a sentence in which I referred to films produced in non-English-speaking countries in languages other than the English language, but with English subtitles added to them:

> ...collections of foreign films with English subtitles...

As an English-speaking person from an English-speaking country, were I speaking to an audience of people from English-speaking countries, that might work. However, my audience consists of people who are not only from English-speaking countries, but from around the world. How can I rephrase the above expression to avoid using the term "foreign"--which is relative to whatever country is "native"--to describe those films, but to still have the meaning of being films that are not produced in the English language?

Comment: @NigelJ That might work here, but I'm also looking for a single word that could replace the compound adjective "non-English" in any context. For instance, if the films didn't have subtitles.

Comment: @NigelJ That would work if I meant English as relating to the country of England/UK, however I'm going to edit the question to specify that I'm asking about the English language, i.e. what's shared between Britons, Americans, Australians etc. I should have specified English language vs. nationality to begin with!

Comment: "An collection of films created in the wonderful world beyond English speaking borders, with English captions to aid their enlightenment"

Comment: Less pithy and less provocative: "Films in languages beyond English, with English subtitles"

Comment: To be specific on production location? : "Films produced beyond the English speaking film industry, with English subtitles"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me like you already know and decided against this option (given you use it in your post), but I think the right expression is, in fact, **non-English** films. Or if you want to be even more clear (and are OK with something longer), **non-English-language** films. Both are used and mean the same thing (films not in the English language).

"Non-English films":

- [Best non-English films - IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/list/ls066858212/)
- [3 Non-English Films That Will Make You Forget You're Reading Subs](https://studybreaks.com/2017/09/08/non-english-films-subtitle-reading/)
- [Is it anti-American to like non-English movies? | Scanners | Roger Ebert](https://www.rogerebert.com/scanners/is-it-anti-american-to-like-non-english-movies)

"Non-English-language films":

- [List of most expensive non-English-language films - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most_expensive_non-English-language_films)
- [If You've Seen 40/100 Of These Non-English Language Films, You're A Serious Film Nerd - BuzzFeed](https://www.buzzfeed.com/jamiejones/how-many-of-these-non-english-movies-have-you-seen?utm_term=.bcM1Y1wqM#.gyNDpD42o)
- [How to handle non english language films? : radarr - Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/radarr/comments/5sn6h9/how_to_handle_non_english_language_films/)

Comment: I was actually looking for a non-compound adjective, but it appears "non-English" is the only expression that includes all languages with the exception of English, which is what I was looking for. Thanks for the examples as well.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer
The following attempts to offer solutions that respond to the dilemma described by the OP. None of the solutions below mean "non-English" as requested in the OP's title.

> Films **made around the world** with English subtitles.

If a film is described as having English subtitles, readers/viewers will infer that it is not in English. Alternatively, may I suggest either mother-tongue, *[one's native language](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mother%20tongue)*,

> Films in **mother-tongue** with English subtitles

or

> **Multinational** films with English subtitles
>   **International** films with ...

Comment: I wonder whether it's going a step too far to suggest that the term be dropped completely: "Films () with English subtitles".

Comment: @Lawrence  I often watch English films with subtitles because I am hard of hearing, and because all too often movie dialogues are mumbled, or softly spoken, certain directors think it adds realism... bah humbug.

Comment: That (*English* films with English subtitles) was part of what I meant by going a step too far. But the OP doesn't seem concerned about excluding English films. He'd probably be happy to include English films so long as non-English films aren't considered 'foreign' when they're in the customer's native language. He doesn't even care if there [aren't subtitles at all](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/426017/whats-a-word-to-describe-something-that-is-non-english/426045?noredirect=1#comment1020663_426017). :)

Comment: "**International** films with English subtitles" is the phrase that I'd go for, and I'm sure I've seen it used in the media.

Comment: As much as I am an optimistic person, it seems that if there is a single word that describes "non-English," it's obscure at best or otherwise nonexistent.

Comment: @AbdullahHussain for a world-wide audience, as you stated in your question, "international" works pretty well, it may not mean "non-English" but movies are also made and seen by Americans, Australians, Canadians, Irish, and South Africans. To categorize their films as being English is reductive and possibly offensive.